# Normal Line Plotting in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a plane given by the equation `12(x-1) + 8(y+2) - z = 0`, whose normal line at the point `(1, -2, 0)` is given by the parametric equations `x = 1 + 12t`,`y = -2 + 8t` and `z = -t`.  When I graph the plane and the normal line in MATLAB, however, the normal line does not appear to be perpendicular to the plane, as it should be, and I believe I'm missing something in how MATLAB is plotting these:

```
x = linspace(0,2);
y = linspace(-3,-1);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

Z = 12*(X - 1) + 8*(Y + 2);
mesh(X,Y,Z);
hold on;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
plot3(1,-2,0, 'x', 'markers', 15);
alpha(0.2);

t = linspace(-0.05,0.05);
xn = 1 + 12*t;
yn = -2 + 8*t;
zn = -t;
plot3(xn,yn,zn, 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image]

Comment: Are yo sure the line equation you use is correct?

Answer (score 0):

To plot a line between two points `a1` and `a2`, you need to separatly give `plot3` their x,y,z coordinates:

```
t = 0.05;
% a1 = [1 -2 0]; 
% a2 = [1+12*t, -2+8*t, -t];
x = [ 1,  1+12*t];
y = [-2, -2+8*t];
z = [ 0, -t];
plot3(x,y,z)
```

In your case, if you want the line to extend on both sides:

```
t = 0.05;
x =  1 +12*t*[1, -1];
y = -2 + 8*t*[1, -1];
z =  0 -   t*[1, -1];
plot3(x,y,z)
```